# dplyr mutate in zoo object

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I was trying to apply the `dplyr mutate` in `zoo` object. But, it generated an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "zoo".
```

I googled and saw that it has not been yet resolved. A recent discussion on this is [here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/lnqN3y7-ysE)

I would appreciate if any one could help me in this regard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

zoo has a `transform` method:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(cbind(a = 1:3, b = 4:6))

transform(z, a = a + 1, c = a + b)
```

giving:

```
  a b c
1 2 4 5
2 3 5 7
3 4 6 9
```

or using `z` from above, the following gives the same result:

```
library(magrittr)
z %>% transform(a = a + 1, c = a + b)
```

Next time please provide sample code, inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will do that from the next time.