# mutate on new variables inside zoo object

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, zoo

I'm interested to compute some new variables inside a `zoo` object. I like the `dplyr`-`mutate`-way, but I can't figure out how to *mutate* inside a `zoo` object. I seem to be limited to computing on variables that already exist inside the object if I use `transform`. I can obviously do it in separate steps, but I imagine there's some handy way to work within `zoo` object I might have overlooked? I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888342/1305688), which inspired my question, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553761/using-dplyr-summary-function-on-yearmon-from-zoo?rq=1), but neither of them solved my specific issue.

Here is  some code demonstrating what I would like to do,

```
df <- data.frame(dta=paste0("2016-11-", 19:24), a = 3:8, b = 9:14)

# install.packages(c("dplyr"), dependencies = TRUE)  
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(c = log(a) * log(b),
          dc = c - lag(c, 1)
          )
#          dta a  b        c        dc
# 1 2016-11-19 3  9 2.413898        NA
# 2 2016-11-20 4 10 3.192061 0.7781628
# 3 2016-11-21 5 11 3.859264 0.6672028
# 4 2016-11-22 6 12 4.452355 0.5930915
# 5 2016-11-23 7 13 4.991161 0.5388060
# 6 2016-11-24 8 14 5.487765 0.4966045

# install.packages(c("zoo"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(zoo)
df.z <- read.zoo(df)

# install.packages(c("magrittr"), dependencies = TRUE)  
library(magrittr)
df.z %>% transform(c = log(a) * log(b), dc = c - lag(c, 1))
# Error in x[seq_len(xlen - n)] : 
#   object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

# the clumsy workaround
df.z.1 <- df.z   %>% transform(c = log(a) * log(b))
df.z.2 <- df.z.1 %>% transform(dc = c - lag(c, 1))
df.z.2
#            a  b        c        dc
# 2016-11-19 3  9 2.413898        NA
# 2016-11-20 4 10 3.192061 0.7781628
# 2016-11-21 5 11 3.859264 0.6672028
# 2016-11-22 6 12 4.452355 0.5930915
# 2016-11-23 7 13 4.991161 0.5388060
# 2016-11-24 8 14 5.487765 0.4966045
```

Comment: Hi, `zoo` use use internally `matrix` for storing data, so may be you can define your issue as `mutate` in `matrix` to get wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting comes from the ambiguity between the `'c'`-column that is in the process of being created and the `c`-function which is the "built-in" being referred to by the error function. You can get success with this one-liner (which is midway between your desire for a single transform call and your undesired 2-step process:

```
> df.z %>% transform('c' = log(a) * log(b) ) %>% transform(dc = c - lag(c, 1))
           a  b        c        dc
2016-11-19 3  9 2.413898        NA
2016-11-20 4 10 3.192061 0.7781628
2016-11-21 5 11 3.859264 0.6672028
2016-11-22 6 12 4.452355 0.5930915
2016-11-23 7 13 4.991161 0.5388060
2016-11-24 8 14 5.487765 0.4966045
```

Experimentation shows that the result of the first "transformation" is not available for further use inside the first transform call. I did also try slipping a call to `... %>% coredata ...` between the zoo object and the transform call but there is also apparently no method for mutate on matrix objects. This works but seems like a step backward:

```
df.z %>% coredata %>% as.data.frame %>% 
                        mutate('c' = log(a) * log(b), dc = c- lag(c,1)  )
```

Comment: I think you want the first alternative presented above.  The second loses the index.

Comment: Agree. I just presented it to demonstrate that it was possible to "pull apart" a zoo-object. The `transform` function seems more generic, although the `mutate`-function has mode compact semantics.

Comment: Only for this problem.  If the problem were to swap two columns then `transform` does it easily but it's not clear at all how to do it with `mutate`. e.g..  using the built in `BOD` data frame: `transform(BOD, demand = Time, Time = demand)` does a swap but that won't work with `mutate`.  One can come up with many similar examples.